# How to implement ADFS in non MVC asp .net application?

Tags: adfs

I would like to implement ADFS authentication in normal asp. net web application. Unfortunatly its not an MVC project.  Let me know if it is possible to do it.

regards,

Swaroop

Comment: Have you searched over the internet something about this question? Do you know what is [google](https://www.google.com)?

Comment: What protocol do you want to use?

Comment: All the examples were with MVC, normal ASp. net application with adfs were not there.